# SQL Developer interprets strings incorrectly from google sheets

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Version 11.2g

I have a lot of strings to copy over from google docs that need to be inserted into rows in SQL Developer.

[image: SQL Developer misinterprets my single quotation marks when copied from docs]

How come if I copy a string from google docs into Oracle SQL Developer, then SQL Developer will change the single quotation marks into  2 different characters with different Unicode values? Oracle will then proceed to say that the ASCII symbols are out of range. Seems like a quirk.

I need it to be like the second row in the image (without manually changing every single quotation mark), but Oracle interprets it as the first row from google docs.

Comment: That isn't SQL Developer's fault; Google docs is using 'curly quotes'. See [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/63237/how-do-i-change-google-docs-default-quotation-symbols), for example.

Answer (score 1):

So you don't have to manually change every quote, you can do a find-replace on:

- opening single quote `‘` (Unicode 145);
- closing single quote `’` (Unicode 146);
- left single quotation mark `‘` (Unicode 8216);
- right single quotation mark `’` (Unicode 8217); or
- single high-reversed quotation mark `‛` (Unicode 8219).

Changing all to a straight single quote `'` (ASCII 36).

You could even do a replacement using the regular expression `[‘’‘’‛]`.

And then verify that the document you are copying from does actually use straight single quotes or that the value being copied is correct (if unwanted). Or [disable smart quotes](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/63237/how-do-i-change-google-docs-default-quotation-symbols) in Google Documents (thanks to [@Alex Poole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64851018/sql-developer-interprets-strings-incorrectly-from-google-sheets/64851088#comment114657307_64851018)'s comment) in the Google document.